# How to compute mean for non zero elements of a 3d volume along one of the dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, average, mean

I have a 3d volume `DxHxW` and I want to compute the mean only for values that are non zero along the `D` dimension to obtain a 2d `HxW` mean for each element. Here is my current implementation by setting everything to `nan` and then computing the `nanmean`. However, it is quite slow, is there a more optimal way to do this in Python?

```
volume_3d[volume_3d == 0] = np.nan
mean_2d = np.nanmean(volume_3d, 0))
mean_2d[np.isnan(mean_2d)] = 0
```

Comment: try to divide the sum along the axis by the non_zero count. I believe it will be much more faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the test array as:

```
D = 2; H = 3; W = 4
volume_3d = np.arange(1, D * H * W + 1, dtype=float).reshape(D, W, H)
volume_3d[0, 1, 0] = volume_3d[0, 2, 1] = volume_3d[1, 2, 1] = 0
```

Actually, in order not to change the source array, your original code
can be rewrittent to the following function:

```
def f1(arr):
    wrk = np.copy(arr)
    wrk[wrk == 0] = np.nan
    mean_2d = np.nanmean(wrk, 0)
    mean_2d[np.isnan(mean_2d)] = 0
    return mean_2d
```

To get the result you can run `res1 = f1(volume_3d)` and the result is:

```
array([[ 7.,  8.,  9.],
       [16., 11., 12.],
       [13.,  0., 15.],
       [16., 17., 18.]])
```

My proposition how to compute this result faster is:

```
def f2(arr):
    cnt = np.sum(arr != 0, axis=0)
    tot = np.sum(arr, axis=0)
    return np.divide(tot, cnt, out=np.zeros_like(tot), where=cnt!=0)
```

Using *%timeit* I compared execution times getting:

- for your code: *330 µs*,
- for my code: *160 µs*,

i.e. my code works over 2 times faster.

Another detail worth to mention is that your code raises *RuntimeWarning:
Mean of empty slice* and mine runs with no warning.

I suppose that for a bigger array the difference should be more apparent.
Try on your own.